# Is there any command to return a zombified piglin to piglin?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to record a story of a piglin that goes to the overworld and becomes a zombified piglin, so the player tries to save it but has to use commands, I would like to know if there is any command to reverse the transformation or to convert one mob to another mob.

Answer (score 1):

I know a command in Java, but for Bedrock you could probably summon a piglin, and then teleport the piglin to the zombified piglin, then kill the zombified piglin.

1. ```
   /summon piglin
   ```
2. ```
   /tp @e(type=piglin) @e(type=zombified_piglin)
   ```
3. ```
   kill @e(type=zombified_piglin)
   ```

Comment: It would be great if you clarified which part of the commands are placeholders, and what they should be replaced with.

Comment: That's do the trick but it's not exactly what I want to do. =(